# nginx rewrites paths proxied to node.js

Tags: node.js, url, nginx, express

I'm trying to make a nodejs website/server download another website when the user goes to a URL looking like this: `http://example.com/test/http://google.com`

The problem is that nginx is rewriting the req.url to `/test/http:/google.com` when it should be `/test/http://google.com`

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', 8080);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/server/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'super-duper-secret-secret' }));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/app/public' }));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app/public'));

    app.enable('trust proxy')

});

app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

require('./app/server/router')(app);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), 'localhost', function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
})
```

**router.js:**

```
app.get('/test/*', function(req, res) {
    console.log("REQ.URL:");
    console.log(req.url);
    res.send('200', req.url);
});
```

example.com file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

```
server {
        server_name example.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.log;
        # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers and much more can be added, see nginx config options
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Is there a way to make nginx not rewrite like it does?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; the slash isn't removed from `req.url`.

Comment: It seems like it's nginx that does the transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fixes the problem.

```
if(req.url.match(/https?:\/[^\/]/)) {
    req.url = req.url.replace(/(https?\:)\/([^\/])/, "$1//$2");
}
```

So the final code looks like this

```
app.get('/test/*', function(req, res) {
    console.log("REQ.URL:");
    console.log(req.url);
    if(req.url.match(/https?:\/[^\/]/)) {
        req.url = req.url.replace(/(https?\:)\/([^\/])/, "$1//$2");
    }
    console.log("REQ.URL FIXED:");
    console.log(req.url);
    res.send('200', req.url);
});
```

If anyone knows how to fix it in Express so that it doesn't rewrite the path I will mark your answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this (untested code) is what you're after:

```
app.get('/test/:url', function(req, res) {
    console.log("req.params.url:", req.params.url);
    res.send('200', req.params.url);
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't even need to bother with the regex. Everything after '/test/' will be stored in the `:url` param.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood my question. The problem is that expressjs rewrites `/test/http://google.com` to `/test/http:/google.com`. Notice the missing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `req.originalUrl`.

```
app.get('/test/*', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    res.send('200', req.originalUrl);
});
```